# Visual Studio package shows Missing but Exists in Specified Location

Tags: c#, .net, reference, csproj

I have a project where it shows a couple of the references as not found on the solution explorer:

[image: Missing References]

However, when I unload the project and look at the references they look like this:

```
<Reference Include="CsvHelper, Version=26.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8c4959082be5c823, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\CsvHelper.27.2.1\lib\net47\CsvHelper.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Flurl, Version=2.8.2.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Flurl.2.8.2\lib\net40\Flurl.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Flurl.Http, Version=2.4.2.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\Flurl.Http.2.3.2\lib\net46\Flurl.Http.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="JetBrains.Annotations, Version=2021.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\JetBrains.Annotations.2021.1.0\lib\net20\JetBrains.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\packages\log4net.2.0.12\lib\net45\log4net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You will notice the paths on each are the same basic location (nuget packages folder for the project).  I have looked at the two showing there that say they are not found and they exist at those locations.  Why would it be saying not found?  The only difference I can find here is the `Private` node but even if I remove that tag it shows the same way.

If I click on the item in solution explorer and look at properties it shows not resolved and has no path.

I have also tried a NuGet package restore which just says everything is already there, which is correct.

I have tried looking at target frameworks too; these packages according to their nuget package folders are net46 and net47 and I'm targeting net48 so it should not be the issue where I'm targeting a lower .net version than the reference.

Why isn't it recognizing the refrence?